# how to use a database's table data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mysql

I have already loaded a MySQL database as a layer, one of the tables contains data that are coordinates of some places, how to plot these data on a map(for example google maps)?

Comment: It sounds like you may have to create the spatial column to be able to display the feature geometry, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/creating-spatial-columns.html

Comment: thanks very much, you are right, i was using integers as data types in my table